# Failure to register Application Insights with Service Fabric app

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

Trying to configure App Insights with a Service Fabric Reliable Actor application. I'm using the latest beta nuget package (Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native).

When I go through the Visual Studio Configure Application Insights menu option, it fails when I hit Register. It has created the App Insights resource in Azure but no data flows to it.

The failure says:

[image]

My packages.config looks like:

`<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.4.0-beta5" targetFramework="net452"/>
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric" version="1.0.0-beta2" targetFramework="net452"/>
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native" version="1.0.0-beta2" targetFramework="net452"/>`

Is this not possible with a beta package? What's the manual approach to doing this if the wizard isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the visual studio `Configure Application Insights` / `Add Application Insights` menu items specify a fixed version (`1.2.3`) for `Microsoft.AppliationInsights` nuget package, rather than fetching the latest stable one and applying that.

On the other hand the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native` has a dependency on version `2.3.0 or higher` of `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights`.

This means, when you already have the `..SF.Native` nuget and go throught the VS menu, it complains about not being able to go to the specified version.

If you would have done things in the reverse order - i.e., Use VS wizard first and then applied the MS.AI.SF.Native nuget, you wouldn't see any issues. `MS.AI.SF.Native` would cleanly update your `MS.AI` nuget.

You mentioned you are using an actor service. You don't really need to do anything in that case, as the add/configure wizard would have added the MS.AI nuget for you - for which you already have a higher version courtesy MS.AI.SF.Native dependency.

For completion sake - If your service needs other AI server functionality (like dependency collection of http calls etc.), you can also manually added the relevant [Applciation Insights for Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web/) nuget package. Although that's not something the VS menu item would add for you actor service (console app).